# Render Cards after fetch data from API and create an object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying to learn ReactJS..
Today I was trying to create an array of objects with fetch results and after that create the cards, but I just can update the state but the cards are not re-render.. can you help me?

App.js

```
  const teamsForLoop = [
    Team1,
    Team2,
    Team3
  ];

  const [allPlayers, setAllPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);
  const [allTeams] = useState(teamsForLoop);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const playerInfo = async() => {
      setLoading(true)
      allTeams.map(async(teamArray) => {
        setTeam([])
        teamArray.map(async (player) => {
          let playerName = player.split(" ");
          const result = await axios.get(
            `https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/2/searchplayers.php?p=${playerName[0]}%20${playerName[1]}`
          );
          if (result.data.player === null) {
            setTeam((state) => {
              return [...state];
            });
          } else {
            setTeam((state) => {
              return [...state, result.data.player[0]];
            });
          }
        });
       setAllPlayers(team);
      });
      setLoading(false);
    };
    playerInfo();
  },[]);

  if (loading) return "...Loading...";

  return (
    <>
      <PlayerList allPlayers={allPlayers} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PlayerList.js

```
function PlayerList({ allPlayers }) {
  const myData = []
  .concat(allPlayers)
  .sort((a, b) => (a.idTeam !== b.idTeam ? 1 : -1))
  return (
    <div>
      {myData.map((player,index) =>
        (
          <div key={index}>       
            ...........
            </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think my problem was on the `useEffect` hook or maybe on my fetch function..
I already have done it using just arrays but without state.

Comment: You are using map but you don't ever assign the result of it anywhere

Comment: So you are saying to use a new variable to store the result of the map too? I'm using the result variable to get just the results from fetch..

Comment: Use forEach instead of map than. I don't know why you update state so many times. You rerender this component 15 times probably before any data is displayed

Comment: Ouuh that's why they print my console.logs a lot of times xD thanks
I will try like you are saying.

Comment: I don't see overt issues with the code that would cause anything to *not* rerender, but there's room for improvement. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces any issues you see that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sorry Just today I got time to continue this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-orla-v872kt?file=/src/PlayerList.js
@Drew Reese
Can you check on the code sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue I see now is that you are attempting to cache the fetched players in the `team` state in the loops and then use the `team` state to update the `players` state. The problem here is that React state updates are asynchronously processed, so `team` hasn't updated when `setAllPlayers(team);` is called.

## Solution

It would be simpler to map the `allTeams` arrays to the GET requests, wait for them to resolve, and enqueue a single `allPlayers` state update. Flatten the arrays of team's players and map these to the axios GET Promise. Wait for these to resolve and map the results to the array of players.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [allPlayers, setAllPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [allTeams] = useState(teamsForLoop);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const playerInfo = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await Promise.all(
      allTeams
        .flat()
        .map((player) =>
          axios.get(
            `https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/2/searchplayers.php?p=${player}`
          )
        )
    );
    const players = response.map((result) => result.data.player[0]);
    setAllPlayers(players);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    playerInfo();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return "...Loading...";

  return <PlayerList allPlayers={allPlayers} />;
}
```

[image: Edit render-cards-after-fetch-data-from-api-and-create-an-object]